# Linking image in SCSS for Laravel

Tags: laravel, sass

I have code in SCSS:

```
$path-img : '../img';
@mixin background-images($img, $background-position, $background-repeat:no-repeat, $background-size:auto, $background-attachment:scroll, $background-color:transparent, $important) {
  /*background-image: url('#{$path-img}/#{$img}');
  background-repeat: $background-repeat;
  background-position: $background-position;
  background-size: $background-size;
  background-attachment: $background-attachment;*/
  background-color: $background-color ;
  background: url('#{$path-img}/#{$img}') $background-repeat $background-attachment $background-position $background-size $important;
}
```

but not think any error compile scss for relative or absolute link in url() function but why?
I trying it ./ or ../ or ~/ but not correct path. :(
but get address [http://127.0.0.1/img/file.jpg](http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/file.jpg) is correct path but not in SCSS why?

My structure Laravel is default and any image is in "img" folder and copy all images in folder storage (this correct?) and copy all images in public folder. Where is started copy img and how correct write path in SCSS?

Comment: 1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors

Comment: https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/url-rewriting